# VS Code keyboard shortcut to show online API document for golang?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'ms using vscode and "go for Visual Studio Code" and vim emulation plugin to set up a golang IDE (keyboard is using vim style)

When I mouse hover an API, the online API document can be displayed.
But is there a keyboard shortcut that can trigger the API document display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `editor.action.showHover` shortcut:
The default key is: `Ctrl+K Ctrl+I` but not works with vim enabled, so you may change it to e.g.: `Ctrl+K Ctrl+K`, this works for me:

You can open this editor by going to the menu under File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on Mac)
then search for Show Hover (or just Hover) and change shortcut for  `editor.action.showHover`, see:

[image]

see:
[image]